# Can a POST request received at Node.js call an Angular component?

Tags: node.js, angular, post, mean-stack

I have a conceptual question in MEAN stack and I hope to get an answer.

Can a POST request received in Node.js trigger/open an Angular component?

When having a MEAN stack app, usually Angular calls node and receives a response, but the starting point is always Angular.

Angular -> Node -> Angular -> Node -> etc.

But, is it possible that the starting point is Node.js?

i.e. Node -> Angular -> Node -> Angular -> etc.

In my specific example, I am receiving a POST request from an external server/app into this URL: http://localhost:3000/ssologin

What I want to do is to retrieve the data in this POST request in Node.js and display an Angular component accordingly (in this case, access to dashboard directly without manual login)

Is it even possible to call an Angular component from Node.js?

Or the communication only works from Angular to Node.js?

i.e. Angular -> Node -> Angular -> Node -> etc.

but not Node -> Angular -> Node -> Angular -> etc.

And if it's not possible to start Angular from Node, If I define a route in Angular to divert the POST request to Angular, how can I share the exact POST request data with node?

Comment: Bit unclear what you mean. You can redirect (serverside) to a different url that runs your angular app..?

Comment: Hi @MikeOne, so the post request is coming to /ssologin. What I meant is that I can create a route in angular called /ssologin instead of creating it in node in case there is a way to retrieve the data in the post request and send it back to node. Please note that I am using an npm library in node that retrieves the data and handle it. So I must keep the same data format if I directed the post request to angular rather than node. This is just assumption. I don't know if it works